# PhpMailer Minimum Username Length for Email

Tags: php, forms, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer to send a form via email. It works but only with an email username of length 7 or greater. Anything less and I get the error "Could not instantiate mail function." I'm using gmail's smtp server and I know that Google only allows account to be made with length >= 6 so I didn't know if that could be interfering? Here is the php file.

```
require_once("../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once('../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$fullname = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$filename = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']);
$filetype = substr($filename, 
            strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
$filesize = $_FILES["resume"]["size"]/2048;

//Honeypot used to catch spam bots
 if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
    echo "SPAM HONEYPOT";
    exit;
}

//Checks for injection
$email = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $email);
$find = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:)/i";
if (preg_match($find, $fullname) || preg_match($find, $email) || preg_match($find, $url) || preg_match($find, $subject)) {
   echo "<h1>Error</h1>\n
      <p>No meta/header injections, please.</p>";
   exit;
}

//Test for valid inputs
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstname) || (empty($firstname))){
    echo 'Invalid first name.';
    exit;
}
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $lastname) || (empty($lastname))){
    echo 'Invalid last name.';
    exit;
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Invalid email format.'; 
    exit;
}
if($filesize > 5){
    echo 'Invalid file size.'; 
    exit;
}

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($email, 'Online Application');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('joe@sample.org', 'Joe Smith');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$jobmessage = 'Joe, </br> You have an applicant for the position' . ' ' . $subject . ' ' . ' whose name is' . ' ' . $fullname . ' ' . 'and email is' . ' ' . $email . '.</br></br>' . 'This is an automated message.';
$mail->msgHTML($jobmessage);
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']);

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Application sent!";
}
```

`

Comment: Post your exact problem. It's really not clear what it is. Much of your validation is wrong or pointless as PHPMailer does most of it for you - for example it won't let you use an invalid address in any field, and filters everything for header injection. You're handling file uploads unsafely, and you're forging the from address; don't do that as you'll just get bounced. It would help if you read the docs and examples that cover all this.

Comment: The file is a work in progress. I have read the docs and examples and many many examples others have posted using the same validations with phpmailer. The problem is that currently the form works except when the email username is less than 7 characters long. That is when I get the error.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read - there are a lot of very poor PHPMailer examples around. Base your code on [a good example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps). PHPMailer works just fine with short email addresses - for example the test suite includes a valid 3-character address. If you want anyone to reproduce and solve you issue, you need to cut down your code to the minimum necessary and provide appropriate data to cause the problem. The act of doing this will probably help you find the problem without having to ask a question.